# How to calculate the resurface rate of a specific value

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'd like to calculate how often a specific site resurfaces more than one time in a given year.

The table looks like so:
site_metrics

```
| site          | date | 
|       abc.com | 20190101 | 
|       abc2.com | 20190102   | 
|       abc2.com | 20190302   | 
|       abc2.com | 20190402   | 
|       abc2.com | 20190502   | 
|       abc3.com | 20190502   | 
|       abc3.com | 20190602   |
```

I'd like to be able to say: x% of sites resurface more than once in a given year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can use two levels of aggregation:

```
select avg(case when num_in_year > 1 then 1.0 else 0 end) as resurface_rate
from (select site, count(*) as num_in_year
      from t
      where date >= '2019-01-01' and date < '2020-01-01'
      group by site
     ) s;
```

If you wanted this per calendar year:

```
select yyyy,
       avg(case when num_in_year > 1 then 1.0 else 0 end) as resurface_rate
from (select site, extract(year from date) as yyyy, count(*) as num_in_year
      from t
      group by site, extract(year from date)
     ) s
group by yyyy;
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL and use **only one** GROUP BY to get `resurface_rate per year`

I am not sure if it has much practical value (as it uses relatively expensive regexp functions and with big number of sites can have scale issue), but as a conceptual version is interesting I think

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION extract_year(date ANY TYPE) AS (
  SUBSTR(date, 1, 4) -- if stored as YYYYMMDD as string
--  EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date) -- if stored as DATE type
); -- just to abstact year extraction from user's data as it is not that important but really depends on how exactly it is stored
SELECT extract_year(date) year, 
  1 - ARRAY_LENGTH(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(REGEXP_REPLACE(
    CONCAT(STRING_AGG(site ORDER BY site), ','), 
    STRING_AGG(DISTINCT CONCAT('(',site,',){2,}'), '|'), 
    ''
  ), ',')) / COUNT(DISTINCT site) AS resurface_rate
FROM  `project.dataset.table`
GROUP BY year
```

If to apply to sample data from your question - result is

```
Row year    resurface_rate   
1   2019    0.6666666666666667
```

Most likely, can be further "streamline" - but just wanted to share this unorthodox version